# How to pass path variables to axios GET request

Tags: vue.js, get, xmlhttprequest, axios, path-variables

I am using axios HTTP library with vuejs to make REST API requests. Now, I have a use case to check if a username exists. Following is the axios request for it

```js
    this.$axios
            .$get("/user/profile/find/username/${username}")
            .then(response => {
              var isUsernameAvailable = response.id == 0 ? true : false;
              resolve(isUsernameAvailable);
            })
```

Here, when I pass the `username` as URI variable, it is passed as plain text. I have looked into axios docs and couldn't find an example how to do this. And then I came across the issue below. So, what I got from this issue is that axios does not support URI variables which is lame for a single purpose HTTP library.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/706

So, now the questions

1. Did I miss something here or axios really don't support URI variables?
2. Are there any straight forward workarounds for this? Or how others are dealing with this.
3. Finally, Vuejs does recommend using axios but what other alternatives should I consider? How about `fetch()` or isomorphic-fetch?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```js
this.$axios
  .$get(`/user/profile/find/username/${username}`)
  .then(response => {
    var isUsernameAvailable = response.id == 0 ? true : false;
    resolve(isUsernameAvailable);
  })
```

Comment: So you are suggesting to use single quotes instead of double?

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary, no, [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to use a back-tick for that. I bothered myself thinking why they used back-tick, after all it works fine. Don't forget your **``** anytime you are passing variables in the URL.